# Decision Analysis in R

Tags: r, decision-tree

I teach courses on business decision-making and more most of the analytic techniques I work with I am working with R. As well, in my consulting practice. One of the modules in the course is Decision Analysis. I have been looking for a package in R that provides this type of probabilistic, Expected Value, Expected Utility type of analysis.

In R's development site, the last entry I saw on the subject (from 2011) says R is not really good at this type of analysis. Is that still the case or are there packages that provide this functionality.

If not, I'll try to put something together once my current programming/writing project is done.

Also, I'm interested in decision trees (not cluster or other classification trees), but trees that partition the probabilities and outcomes of a chain of decisions. Anything in R besides rpart? Plenty in Excel, but I'm trying to wean students off Excel and get them thinking more about what they are trying to achieve.

Thanks for the help.

Jim Hunter

Comment: Quick-R lists some tree-based models: http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cart.html

Comment: As usual, try `library("sos"); findFn("{decision analysis}")`; it finds the `utility` package (and a few other bits and pieces).  I don't know if it's what you need or not.

Comment: I do not agree that this is a bad question. I don't think the critics understand the problem domain. Nevertheless:

I did find the pmr package that supports Analyitic Heirarchacal Process which is commonly used for decision analysis. I don't think this package is suitable for use by business students, but if you do decide to write something, maybe you could put a nice front-end on the pmr package functions.

See paper:
http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/86/art%253A10.1186%252F1471-2288-13-65.pdf?auth66=1395456974_244987ef5cf77bdf238d6252fa9e3e1f&ext=.pdf

Comment: Take a look at the (data.tree)[https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/index.html] package. I used it as the basis for a decision analysis GUI that is part of the business analytics tool (Radiant)[https://radiant-rstats.github.io/docs/]. For documentation and examples see https://radiant-rstats.github.io/docs/model/dtree.html