# How to draw straight-edged decision trees in data.tree?

Tags: r, tree

I have several functions implemented based on the `data.tree` package suggested for decision analysis by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280312/decision-analysis-in-r).

Next I would like to make good-looking trees as in this one:
[image: From commercial program (TreeAge)]

But all I could get is this one:
[image: My own code]

How can I draw out straight edges as above? I don't mind the colour, though.

Here is my code:

```
library(data.tree)
library(yaml)
library(DiagrammeR)

node=as.Node(yaml.load("
name: Plaintiff to Litigate?
type: decision
Litigate:
    type: chance
    Prove negligence, Win Case:
        type: chance
        p: 0.60
        High damages:
            type: terminal
            p: 0.30
            payoff: 2900000
        Medium damages:
            type: terminal
            p: 0.40
            payoff: 1900000
        Low damages:
            type: terminal
            p: 0.30
            payoff: 900000
    Fail to prove negligence:
        type: terminal
        p: 0.40
        payoff: -100000
Settlement Offer:
    type: terminal
    payoff: 1000000"))



GetPrelimNodeLabel = function(node) switch(node$type, 
                                                                                     terminal = format(node$payoff, scientific = FALSE, big.mark = ","),'')

GetEdgeLabel = function(node) {
    if (isNotRoot(node) && node$parent$type == 'chance') {
        label = paste0(node$name, " (", node$p, ")")
    } else {
        label = node$name
    }
    return (label)
}

GetNodeShape = function(node) switch(node$type, decision = "box", chance = "circle", terminal = "none")

GetArrowHead = function(node) switch(node$type, terminal = "oinv", "none")


SetEdgeStyle(node, fontname = 'helvetica', label = GetEdgeLabel, arrowhead=GetArrowHead)
SetNodeStyle(node, fontname = 'helvetica', label = GetPrelimNodeLabel, shape = GetNodeShape)

ToDiagrammeRGraph(node,direction = "climb") %>%
    set_global_graph_attrs("layout", "dot", "graph") %>%
    add_global_graph_attrs("rankdir", "LR","graph") %>%
    render_graph()
```